# Getting the wrong position from QMainWindow geometry()

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am using a class inheriting QMainWindow in a Qt GUI, and another class that handles game logic.

The purpose of the code is to place a UI element at a specific position in the window (as well as move them around as needed.) But, I am having issues. If I increase the size of the window, the Y axis gets larger than the window and places the object below the fold.

game.h

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include "util.h"
#include "myrect.h"

class Game: public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

  TheColony * TC;
public:
  Game(TheColony * ThC);
  QRect getBoard(){ return QRect(0,0,TC->geometry().width(),TC->geometry().height()); }
private slots:
  virtual void periodic();
protected:
  QGraphicsScene * scene;
  QGraphicsView * view;
  MyRect * player;
  QTimer * periodic_timer;
};

#endif // GAME_H
```

game.cpp

```
#include "game.h"

Game::Game(TheColony * ThC)
  : TC(ThC){
  //prepare the scene and view
  scene = new QGraphicsScene(getBoard(),TC);
  view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
  view->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
  view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
  view->setGeometry(getBoard());
  view->show();
  TC->setCentralWidget(view);

  //setup the player's position and size
  player = new MyRect(QRect((view->width()/2) - 50,view->height() - 100,100,100));
  player->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
  scene->addItem(player);
  player->setFocus();

  //timer used to trigger periodic checks.
  periodic_timer = new QTimer();
  connect(periodic_timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(periodic()));
  periodic_timer->start(500);
}

void Game::periodic(){
  static int tcHeight = getBoard().height();
  if(tcHeight != getBoard().height()){
      view->setGeometry(getBoard());
      player->setRect(player->rect().x(), getBoard().height() - 100,100,100);
      tcHeight = getBoard().height();
    }
}
```

On load, square is positioned as expected.
[image: expected]
After resizing the window larger than the original, the square falls below the fold.
[image: unacceptable]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was solved by freqlabs on discord (Who does not have a stack overflow account.)

I was failing to update QGraphicsScene's rect;

```
scene->setSceneRect(getBoard());
```

This left the coordinate space for the scene incorrect and caused the object to be translated wrong. I misunderstood how exactly Qt was using coordinates, I did not realize it used actual coordinate spaces with matrix translations.